# Eclipse Web development tool: How to easily find the definition of an object, whose constructor is in .js file

Tags: eclipse, web, webrtc

I am a newbie of web development.
I am following the tutorial step 4 of [WebRTC codelab](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab)
It has a index.html, which includes adapter.js

In order to easily follow definitions of functions, objects, etc, I build an empty static web development in Eclipse.
And copy the whole folder of Step4 in WebRTC codelab tutorial code.
The file structure is:
WebContent
    js
        lab
          adapter.js
    index.html
    sever.js

Now in index.html, I highlight the word "**RTCPeerConnection**"
in the sentence:

```
window.localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
```

I push "F3", which is supposed to lead me to the definition of RTCPeerConnection.
But nothing happened.

I wonder: How can I find the definition of RTCPeerConnection in an easy way, like the way in java projects?
Or should I use other tools?

Comment: How is it to find the definition when it is a browser supplied API?

Comment: In adapter.js, there is a definition for RTCPeerConnection, which is:  var RTCPeerConnection = null;  Then depending on moz or chrome, it is defined as mozRTCPeerConnection or webkitRTCPeerConnection.

Comment: So you want that definition and not the Actual function definition of moz or webkit?

Comment: Yes. My current purpose is to get familiar with the IDE tool on web development. So I want to know how to find the definition of the object in index.html, which is in a .js file.